# Boolean+surface subdivision=trashed model

Tags: subdivision-surface, boolean-modifier

[image]I have made a simple pumpkin, I want to cut out a face from it, first off I spent all day fighting with this(crash after crash), removing doubles merging verts etc., I have searched and read a lot of threads and I still cannot get a clean cut, when I add the Boolean and hide the item getting cut, it's perfect (WHY!!!?????) but applying it it screws everything up. I'm using a svg, extruded, converted to mesh etc. I am really heated over this as I have never had so much trouble with a Boolean before (new to blender but not 3D) and I don't feel like either is overly complex (maybe when it makes the cuts?)I'm only using it to make a 2.5 d image not a 3D game assent or anything like that, I just wanted to make a lit up pumpkin with a simple face cut out of it. I would add the file here but not sure how? Do i need to link to my google drive or something? I'm using the latest version of blender. I know I'm missing something and any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkHKgTexVdoPfmaXrh4ghHHBsgD3QYQj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, yes please share your file, you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or link to another platform

Comment: ok think that did it, it's currently set up to the point of applying the Boolean

Answer (score 1):

You've put the *Boolean* after the *Subdivision Surface*, it (kind of) works as long as you don't apply the *Boolean* because the *Subdivision Surface* gives enough topology to make the *Boolean* work not too bad, but if you apply the *Boolean* it will be applied on the original low-poly mesh, as if the *Boolean* was in first position in your modifiers stack, which gives a bad result:

[image]

So you need to apply the *Subdivision Surface* first to make the *Boolean* work correctly. The problem is that to make it work correctly the *Subdivision Surface* needs a high subdivision, like 4 or more, which makes a high-poly and heavy object.

The real solution would be to apply to simplify your object: Don't give it thickness for the moment, simplify your boolean object for example with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, apply the *Boolean*, correct the topology manually, and when you're good give a *Subdivision Surface* with a level of 2 which is enough in most of the cases if the topology is correct.

Comment: just an additional hint: you could also use subdivision surface just for parts (just the cut parts) with geometry nodes. By this the model won't be "that" high poly.

Comment: OK interesting I didn't know that ;)

Comment: okay, i swear today has been a bad day to be touching tech. i reopened the file and what you said, was how it was, meaning the subdivision was on the top(maybe i played with it a bit more after i posted?), just for shits and giggles i tried to apply the subdivision and wth it did it, then applied the boolean and it also worked, im am speechless, i just don't get it. But i really do appreciate the responses and you taking the time to explain which makes a lot of sense i spent all day playing with it and now all the sudden it just worked i am going to try to do another cut and see what happens.

Comment: it works for the reason I gave in my answer, your Boolean will work on a high poly, not on a low poly, but I don't recommend applying the Subdivision Surface

Comment: you don't understand, I did all sorts ofa  number of combinations, including what you suggested, which, im sure i had tried and when i opened the file it was already setup that way, im really stumped, blender crashed on me so many times today, then all the sudden it works. I did apply the subdivision and it worked instantly, i redid the same steps for the mouth and it worked instantly. Idk. I am just happy it worked. Thank you!